# Mysql query error sql syntax pdo

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, pdo

This is mysql code im trying to run:

```
SELECT i.id, i.courseid, i.title, i.info, i.lasteditedby, u.id, u.forename, u.surname
FROM courseinformation as i JOIN users AS u ON (i.lasteditedby = u.id)
WHERE i.courseid = :courseid
ORDER BY i.id desc LIMIT 2;
```

Im getting this error :

```
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':courseid ORDER BY i.id desc LIMIT 2' at line 1 */
```

My aim is to get id, courseid, title, info, lasteditedby from CourseInformation table, and then Id, forename and surname from user table. Where the userid is the same as lasteditedby.

I really can't see what sql syntax is wrong as i've used

```
:courseid
```

in other pdo sql querys that ive run

---

for reference, this is my php code with that sql in

```
        $courseid = 'G11111';
        $sql = "SELECT i.id, i.courseid, i.title, i.info, i.lasteditedby, u.id, u.forename, u.surname FROM courseinformation as i JOIN users AS u ON (i.lasteditedby = u.id) WHERE i.courseid = :courseid ORDER BY i.id desc LIMIT 2";
        $sql->bindParam(":courseid", $courseid);
                    $sql->execute();

        foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
            echo '<div class="announceTitle">';
            echo $row['title'].'<br />';
            echo $row['forename'].' '.$row['surname'].'<br />';
            echo '</div>
                <div class="announceText">';
            echo $row['info'];
            echo '</div>
                <br />
                <br />';
        }
```

Could anyone please point me in the direction as to what is wrong?
Thanks for reading

Comment: I don't understand .. `$sql` is a string, so calling `bindParam` on it should give a fatal PHP error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't created a statement handle, you've created a string.

The [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) recommends this:

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT i.id, i.courseid, i.title, i.info, i.lasteditedby, u.id, u.forename, u.surname FROM courseinformation as i JOIN users AS u ON (i.lasteditedby = u.id) WHERE i.courseid = :courseid ORDER BY i.id desc LIMIT 2");
$sth->bindParam(":courseid", $courseid);
```

That later you execute this string with `$db->query` is where the error results, and is a sign you probably need better examples to work from, since this seems to be a few contradictory techniques being applied at the same time.